# Show card option teams and webchat is working differently

Tags: chatbot, adaptive-cards, web-chat

In chatbot , we have created an adaptive card with submit action and show card option for giving the feedback. But the UI look is different in Teams and Webchat.

Teams :

[image]

Webchat :

[image]

Can any one help on this issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected outcome and by-design for the most part. Per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/#how-they-work):

> For example, Contoso Bot can author an Adaptive Card through the Bot
> Framework, and when delivered to Skype, it will look and feel like a
> Skype card. When that same payload is sent to Microsoft Teams, it will
> look and feel like Microsoft Teams.